# SpringSession SecurityContext Auth token not persisting

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

I'm working on implementing SpringSession on an application with SpringSecurity using xml configuration. I followed this guide and the application is working 95%, confirmed that it is hitting the redis backend: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/security.html

The application stores some information in a custom authentication token that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. After implementing spring session, it seems like the data stored in the token is going to the wrong place or not persisting. The flow is like this:

1. Request is made and mapped to the Controller
2. The Controller gets the AuthorenticationToken in a fashion like this `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`
3. This token is the custom token that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and a custom field is set like `token.setFoo("bar")`
4. The controller is finished and returns a ModelAndView with a redirect command like this `redirect:/nextController`
5. In the logs I see after the controller is finished, `Chain processed normally` and `SecurityContextHolder now cleared` and later, `Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`
6. At this point, the field that I set in the auth token inside the SecurityContext, `token.setFoo("bar")`, is null.

If I disable the SpringSession configuration I can see that application uses a cookie called JSESSIONID instead of a cookie called SESSION and that the authentication token is populated and persists correctly.

Any help on this very troublesome bug would be greatly appreciated, thanks!